# arrange delete the data frame row names

Tags: r

I have this dataframe
[image: data frame]

When I try to arrange it to create a ranking variable

```
df_tablaCruzada<-df_tablaCruzada%>%
arrange(desc(Total)) %>%
mutate(Ranking=1:nrow(df_tablaCruzada))
```

I get the data frame arranged and the ranking variable is fine but I have lost the original row names
[image: arrange]

Any idea, please?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dplyr does't support row.names you may want to use tibble::rownames_to_column()

Example

```
mtcars %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column()
```

In your case this should work

```
df_tablaCruzada<-df_tablaCruzada%>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
  arrange(desc(Total)) %>%
  mutate(Ranking=1:nrow(df_tablaCruzada))
```

you can also use the add_row function of dplyr to replace the mutate in this case